# CSS animation and transition switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I have a loading bar program that has a circle moving from left to right with a @keyframes animation. That works just fine.
*however*, I have some JS JQuery that changes a  bar below the animating circle. 
After the progress bar reaches 100, it tells the CSS to add a class called .tocenter
I know it's actually adding the class becuase when I inspect element, the html has the .tocenter class.
The class makes the circle go to the center (left:50%) as well as turn blue. 
The @keyframes animation, however, takes precedence and the transition to the center doesn't show.
I had an "animation-play-state: paused;" added to the .tocenter class, but it doesn't change the left or the background-color elements.

What should i do?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You could possibly have the animation applied to a different class selector that gets removed when the .toCenter class gets added. I'm not sure how well that will work. Maybe if you post the sections of jquery and css that are relevant I can help more.